# Goland main.go dont see func from another local pkg

Tags: function, import, package, goland

I use a func that I wrote in another file which contained in another package but for something main.go are not see that func

./go.mod

```
module Bot

go 1.19
```

./main.go

```
package Bot
func main() {
        nodeInfo() //Unresolved reference 'nodeInfo'
}
```

./pkg/node.go

```
package pkg
func nodeInfo{...something here}
```

Sry if my question is too stupid:)

Comment: Your function is not exported from `pkg` package: https://go.dev/tour/basics/3

Comment: Also, consider rename `Bot` package to `main`or if you won't be able to run it: https://go.dev/doc/code#Command